# How to create an interactive image in Android?

Tags: android, android-view

I want to put a photo in Android app that you can touch it in some parts and can edit it with an EditText, Check Box, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class as a basis for this. You can draw bitmaps, text, and perform image manipulations on the Canvas.

[CanvasView](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView) is a nice simple API that builds on Canvas allowing you to draw/erase and add text/images onto a Canvas easily.